# What is the difference between toGMTstring() and toUTCstring()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am saving data in [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) server from [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) application (using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html)).

Consider following code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schemaObj = new Schema({
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    Datefield: Date//So on...
});

mongooseDB = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://myserver:port/DBname');
mongooseDB.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'error in connection'));

mongooseDB.once('open', function (err) {
        var objmodel = db.model('myschema', schemaObj); 
        modelObj.field1 ='value1'; 
        modelObj.Datefield = new Date().toGMTString(); //new Date().toUTCString();
        //So on..
        modelObj.save(function (err) {
            if (err)    
                 //Notify err
            else
                //DO some task after save
        });

    });
```

In the Datefield, Getting following value when I use 'toGMTstring()' or 'toUTCstring()'

```
 'Thu, 24 Jan 2013 05:49:04 GMT'
```

I went through the following links:

- [toUTCstring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)
- [toGMTstring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toGMTString)

**toGMTString is deprecated and should no longer be used**

Could anyone help me in understanding, whats the difference between toUTCstring() and toGMTstring() with respect to Node.js?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

GMT and UTC are different timezones, they are [Greenwich Mean Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time) and [Coordinated Universal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) Time respectively. GMT is a 'solar' timezone, whereas UTC is 'atomic'. For most purposes they are essentially the same thing, however UTC is more 'universal'.

Interestingly the documentation you point to for `toUTCString` still show a GMT output:

```
var today = new Date();
var UTCstring = today.toUTCString();
// Mon, 03 Jul 2006 21:44:38 GMT
```

For interchange of data between application I would prefer to use something like [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which uses the 'Z' suffix for UTC:

```
2013-01-16T08:19Z
```

Where the 'Z' confusingly stands for 'Zulu time'!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see they are the same. And the documentation at MDN already states that `toGMTString` has been deprecated in favor of `toUTCString`:

> toGMTString() is deprecated and should no longer be used. It remains implemented only for backward compatibility; please use toUTCString() instead.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly use for formatting date and time (Human Readable). 
You can also use [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

```
var event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));

var options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
```

Answer (score -3):

for **ISO** use `toISOString()`

```
var today = new Date();
var ISOstring = today.toISOString();
// 2020-08-03T23:59:58.123Z
```